# ANDROID - Disable Phone Heads Up

Tags: java, android

In API 23+ i need to know how disable the Phone Heads Up when my app starts.

I can do it manually by the smarthphone setting , but i have not found how to do it in the code.

**PRACTICALLY I HAVE TO CHANGE THIS IN THE APP CODE**

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq5z5.png)

Comment: Thats called a notification and you cannot disable notifications for other apps

Comment: Please see the edit in main post

Comment: Your edit does not change the fact that you cannot disable another apps notifications

Comment: It is possibile to open that settings acvity via code and sugges the user to disable that option ?